# Cloudflare - iptables restore real ips to limit connections per ip CentOS 7

Tags: centos, centos7, iptables, cloudflare

im using CentOS 7.

is it some how still possible while using Cloudflare to get the real Visitors IP on the
Backend Server and then limit the Real Users IP Connections through iptables?

Because right now its not possible because it will just limit Cloudflares IPs not the Users IP.

Already tried it with the **mod_cloudflare** but no success results.

**Example**:

```
netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Will print all Cloudflare IPs & not the real Visitors IPs..

**I need it because** a bot-network was simply requesting a „legite“ URL from the website, however the bot-network did is so fast in an huge amount
that the webserver was just not able to handle it.

Hope for some help & hope you understand my Issue/Question.

Answer (score 0):

**mod_cloudflare** is a module designed for the apache web server. It will actually show the real ip addresses for your website visitors but that happens strictly in the apache access logs not on your linux system by using the `netstat` command. If you use `netstat` it will show ip addresses from CloudFlare.

**mod_cloudflare** uses some specific HTTP headers (CF-Connecting-IP) in order to show real ip addresses for your visitors.

More informations about the HTTP headers here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers

You should try to extract the information you need from the web server logs and not by using `netstat`

**UPDATE:**

You could use CSF Firewall that comes with a feature that uses Cloudflare API and add the ip blocks directly into Cloudflare rather that blocking IPs on the server. As I said before, **mod_cloudflare** will show real ips in the web server logs while on the server you will always see ip addresses from Cloudflare. What CSF does though, is using **mod_cloduflare**, extracting real ip addresses from the web server logs and using **Cloudflare API** it adds blocks on those ip addresses or ranges directly in the Cloudflare firewall.

You can read more info about CSF here (chapter 27):
https://download.configserver.com/csf/readme.txt

Just keep in mind that there's a standard limit of 1000 ip addresses or ranges in the Cloudflare's firewall (at least for the free accounts). When you reach 1000, you have to delete older entries so you can add more.

Comment: Hey, thanks finally someone answered.
Im still testing arround, but how is it possible to limit it with iptables the visitors ips. 
Or is this not possible?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope it will make you a better idea about how to proceed

Comment: So i installed CSF, whitelisted all Cloudflare IP's in CSF and installed mod_cloudflare for CSF. So but its not working correctly, its not blocking the limit connection per ip. Could you or someone else give me a small explanation? i want to limit 20 connections per IP (not Cloudflares ip) the real visitor origin ip.

Comment: You can’t limit that. As I said, iptables will always sees the incoming ips as from Cloudflare. Only in apache or nginx logs you can actually see the real ips of your visitors